# How to map IEnumerable<SelectListItem> to IList<> for ListBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, object, orm

I have two classes. Class1 and Class2.

```
public class Class1{
   ...
   public virtual IList<Class2> Class2s{get;set;}
   ...
}
public class Class2{
   ...
   public virtual IList<Class1> Class1s{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

The view contains

```
<%=Html.ListBox("Class2s",
                        ViewData.Model.Class2s.Select(
                                                    x => new SelectListItem {
                                                        Text = x.Name,
                                                        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                        Selected =  ViewData.Model.Class1.Class2s.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)
                                                    })
```

They have many to many mapping. I have a ListBox in Class1 view which displays Class2. How to map the output of the ListBox back to IList Class2s property of Class1? I am able to display the values in the ListBox but unable to map back the SelectListItem to IList.

Comment: You should stop coding your application in the view. And you need to explain, do you want to map _after POST_ of your form, or inside view.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would like to map inside view. This way I directly get the mapped object instead of getting it explicitly from Repository using the Id.

Answer (score 0):

[ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) will do it.  You'll have to import the `System.Linq` namespace in your aspx page.

Comment: Html.ListBox will accept IEnumerable<SelectedListItem>. So where do I need to call ToList()?